# What is wrong with this function I wrote?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Why doesn't my function work? I want the numbers that are put into the input fields to add automatically to the "Lower Section Total" box.

```
      3 of a kind: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      4 of a kind: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Full House: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Little Straight: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Lg. Straight: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      <b>Yahtzeebeshy:</b> <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Chance: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Lower Section Total: <input type="text" id="LowerSectionTotal">

function findTotalB() {
  var arrB = document.getElementsByName('qtyB');
  var totB = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrB.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arrB[i].value))
      totB += parseInt(arrB[i].value);
  }

  document.getElementById('LowerSectionTotal').value = totB;

}
```

Comment: The code shown doesn't call the function.

Comment: This is another way to approach it: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/h2f2r45j/

Answer (score 0):

```
function findTotalB() {
  var arrB = document.getElementsByName('qtyB');
  var totB = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arrB.length; i++) {
     var value = 0 ;

     try {
        value = parseInt(arrB[i].value.trim());
     } catch ( e ) {
     }

     totB += value ; 
  }

  document.getElementById('LowerSectionTotal').value = totB;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is perfectly fine. You can see that in the fiddle below. I have set it to run every second, and you can see that it updates the total as you go on typing the values in other inputs.

Now what you want is to bind to a text [change event](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiO6LGzn87VAhVFLY8KHUEeBLkQFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FEvents%2Fchange&usg=AFQjCNGC0uF517WZTEvyIJw9Gg56ihDEkg) to the source inputs, and call your `findTotalB` function when their value changes.

```js
function findTotalB() {
  var arrB = document.getElementsByName('qtyB');
  var totB = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrB.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arrB[i].value))
      totB += parseInt(arrB[i].value);
  }

  document.getElementById('LowerSectionTotal').value = totB;
}

setInterval(findTotalB, 1000);
```

```html
3 of a kind: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
<br> 4 of a kind: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
<br> Full House: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
<br> Little Straight: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
<br> Lg. Straight: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
<br>
<b>Yahtzeebeshy:</b> <input type="text" name="qtyB">
<br> Chance: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
<br> Lower Section Total: <input type="text" id="LowerSectionTotal">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var arrB = document.getElementsByName('qtyB');
function findTotalB() {
  
  var totB = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrB.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arrB[i].value))
      totB += parseInt(arrB[i].value);
  }

  document.getElementById('LowerSectionTotal').value = totB;

}
for(var i = 0; i < arrB.length; i++) {
 arrB[i].onkeyup = findTotalB; 
}
```

```html
3 of a kind: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      4 of a kind: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Full House: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Little Straight: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Lg. Straight: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      <b>Yahtzeebeshy:</b> <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Chance: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Lower Section Total: <input type="text" id="LowerSectionTotal">
```

Your function is fine, the code just listens if the `qtB` has been typed, and if it is, your function `fundTotalB` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findTotalB() {
  var arrB = document.getElementsByName('qtyB');
  var totB = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrB.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arrB[i].value))
      totB += parseInt(arrB[i].value);
  }

  document.getElementById('LowerSectionTotal').value = totB;

}
```

```html
  3 of a kind: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      4 of a kind: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Full House: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Little Straight: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Lg. Straight: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      <b>Yahtzeebeshy:</b> <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Chance: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Lower Section Total: <input type="text" id="LowerSectionTotal">

<button onClick="findTotalB()" > Click </button>
```

You can add function trigger. Or you can add all input `onchange="findTotalB()"`. That trigger if any input will change, automatically function process.

```
<input onchange="findTotalB()" type="text" name="qtyB">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update automatically to the `Lower Section Total` box then bind `findTotalB()` to `keydown` event. When user types in input and `Lower Section Total` box will get automatically updated

```js
function findTotalB() {
  var arrB = document.getElementsByName('qtyB');
  var totB = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrB.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arrB[i].value))
      totB += parseInt(arrB[i].value);
  }

  document.getElementById('LowerSectionTotal').value = totB;

}

// Binding 'keydown' event
var arrB = document.getElementsByName('qtyB');
var ln = arrB.length;
for (var i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
  document.getElementsByName('qtyB')[i].addEventListener("keydown", findTotalB, false);
}
```

```html
3 of a kind: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      4 of a kind: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Full House: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Little Straight: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Lg. Straight: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      <b>Yahtzeebeshy:</b> <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Chance: <input type="text" name="qtyB">
      <br>
      Lower Section Total: <input type="text" id="LowerSectionTotal">
```